# Tips / Resources for building a Google Chrome plugin

Tags: browser, plugins, google-chrome

After test driving Google Chrome for 30 minutes or so, I like it, even if it seems bare-bones at the moment.  The obvious way to add a few things I can't live without would be through plugins.  Does anyone have any links to resources on how to get started building a plugin/addon for Chrome?  Thanks.

Comment: Note: Plugins(NPAPI) and extensions(JS Based) are not the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/common-google-chrome-objections/) (the Google
 SEO guru)  has a Q&A about chrome, and
 writes about it:

> Q: But I can’t install extension X! Google Chrome is dead to me if I can’t use extension X!
> A: Then you’ll have to use another browser for a while. Google Chrome currently doesn’t support browser extensions (it does support plug-ins, such as Flash). I’m sure that extensions/add-ons are something that the Chrome team would like to do down the road, but the Chrome team will be a bit busy for a while, what with the feedback from the launch plus working on Mac and Linux support. I’d suggest that you give Google Chrome a try for a few days to see if enjoy browsing even without extension X. A lot of really cool extension-like behaviors such as resize-able textareas and drag-and-drop file upload are already built into Google Chrome.

Comment: Google Chrome 4, which is available in the beta channel, now supports extensions, although the extension model and bundle format are different from Firefox.

Comment: Google Chrome 4?!?!?! I'm using Chrome 9! Wow, a lot can change in 10 months...

Answer (score 9):

> Q: But I can’t install extension X! Google Chrome is dead to me if I can’t use extension X!
>
> A: No worries! Now google chrome has extensions too. Look [here](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/?hl=en).

If anyone's interested in chrome extension development here is a [link](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html) to the latest extension developers documentation page for Google chrome.

NOTE: Plugins (NPAPI) and extensions(JS Based) are not the same

From the doc...

> Extensions are small software programs
> that can modify and enhance the
> functionality of Google Chrome.
>
> You write them using web technologies
> like HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. So if
> you know how to write web pages, you
> already know most of what you need to
> know to write extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Chromium supports [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugins which is harder to program compared to Firefox extensions. However NPAPI has better performance and is more versatile.

Checkout this [minimalistic example of an NPAPI plugin.](http://git.webvm.net/?p=npsimple)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does support the netscape plugin api, but that is for displaying certain kinds of content.

You seem to be after a extention api, really firefox is the only major browser to encourage and support third party extentions to browsing capability (that aren't simply new toolbars)

Nothing in the developer documentation points to a browser enhancing api - google seem to want to keep a tight reign on the look and feel of the application.

You might find a more conclusive answer on the development site:

dev.chromium.org, and some of the developers might be on irc on #chromium on freenode.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome now supports extensions and themes.  [Here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html) is the documentation for developing extensions, and [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide) is a page which describes theme creation.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is out of date. A couple of useful URLs:

- For developers: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html
- For end users: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home?hl=en-US

There's a difference between a 'plugin' and an 'extension'. Chrome supports NPAPI plugins:

- http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Chrome may also support a new Pepper Plugin API (ppapi):

- http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/